# what "did" means in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have been mainly developed in Java and JavaScript languages​​.

So whether I'm not sure what "did" means in swift or objective-c.

```
protocol DiceGameDelegate {
    func gameDidStart(game: DiceGame)
    func game(game: DiceGame, didStartNewTurnWithDiceRoll diceRoll: Int)
    func gameDidEnd(game: DiceGame)
}
```

Comment: did as in `didStartNewTurnWithDiceRoll`, `gameDidStart` and `gameDidEnd`? It means that the action has finished running and calling back to your code. It really plain english.

Comment: I'm just awestruck wondering what they are making of some of the emoji code examples. Is this someone who is REALLY worried about what "operator overloading" might mean?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/did

Comment: Just think of it as being named onGameStarted, onGame, onGameEnded, etc. That's what I think they should have used for the API when they developed Cocoa. The 'did' naming sounds rather awkward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have to perform an action called "`anAction`" and the possible delegate calls are taken place something like this.

**willPerform** anAction [might be a delegate call, before perform anAction]

**perform** anAction

**didPerform** anAction [might be a delegate call, anAction has been already performed]

same applies to `UIViewController` `lifecycle` too.

**viewDidLoad** - view has been loaded now

**viewWillAppear** - view is going to load

**viewDidAppear** - view has already loaded

**viewWillDisappear** - view is going to disappear

**viewDidDisappear** - view has already disappeared

it is same as English grammar.

**`Will` for future and `did` for past.**